# How to crop and rotate the video in Android using crop image and convert image libraries?

Tags: android, image, video, ffmpeg, android-image

I am creating an app for Android with a crop Image / Crop Video functionality. For iOS this app is already created.

For iOS is used the lib for edit the video [LLVideoEditor](https://github.com/omergul123/LLVideoEditor)
and the lib for the image crop and rotate [TOCropViewController](https://github.com/TimOliver/TOCropViewController)

For Android I found [uCrop](https://github.com/Yalantis/uCrop) library for Image cropping and [ffmpeg-for-Android](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java) library for the video cropping.

To crop video, I take the first frame of the video, and after that I crop it with uCrop library to receive the coordinates of cropping. (X, Y, Width, Height, rotate Angle).
The received coordinates I pass as command to the `ffmpeg-for-Android` as command line.
The command looks like:

*To crop video I use the command:*

```
ffmpeg -y -i /sdcard/video/in.mp4 -vf crop=Width:Height:X:Y /sdcard/video/out.mp4
```

*To crop and rotate video by 90 degree ClockWise I use the command:*

```
ffmpeg -y -i /sdcard/video/in.mp4 -vf crop=Width:Height:X:Y transpose=1 /sdcard/video/out.mp4
```

The issues that I have:

1. When I choose the crop image area and press rotate image by 90 degree and press apply, the uCrop library returns me X, Y, croppedImageWidth, croppedImageHeight, Angle. In this case Y should be equals 0, but I receive Y > 0, i.e. Y = height of Black area above the image. The uCrop library does not do the correct image zooming after the crop image area is selected.

[image]

2. Converting the video with ffmpeg library works very slowly. The video I convert has only 5 second lenght, so the converting should be quick. But it takes about 15 seconds. In comparison with iOS it takes very very long.

The questions are:
1. Is this way I choose to crop video is the right one?
2. Where can I find the similar libraries for Android as for iOS that will allow me to have the same functionality for Android app as iOS app already has, i.e. receive the right crop image coordinates and quick crop video?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45 it mentioned a lot of libraries for image manipulation, it's useful and very informative, qualitative libraries